# Selenium/Python - message "Unable to find a matching set of capabilities" with older versions of Firefox (31.8.0esr)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I need to use FF31esr with selenium/python on Debian
When doing everything with FF60esr - everything working fine
But as I switch to FF31esr I got this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

I use Debian9 linux, latest versions of Selenium and Geckodriver, Python3.5
Firefox 60.7.0esr installed on debian by default, I downloaded and unzipped Firefox 31.8.0 to /opt/firefox-31.8.0esr/

So this code is working fine (it starts FF60esr)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://google.com')
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

But when I execute this code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
binary = FirefoxBinary('/opt/firefox-31.8.0esr/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

then I got:

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

I fount here on StackOverflow decision with use of DesiredCapabilities - `cap["marionette"] = False` - but it not working for me
I'm doing:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False
binary = FirefoxBinary('/opt/firefox-31.8.0esr/firefox')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap, firefox_binary=binary)
```

and got another **error**:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

Comment: I tried to check with other versions of FF ESR. So now I know that **firefox-52.8.1esr** working good, but **firefox-45.9.0esr** and all minor versions resulting same _Unable to find a matching set of capabilities_ error. But what I need - is using version 31 or less... So is there a way to say selenium to use another set of capabilities (or what it needs) ?

Comment: newest geckodriver doesn't work with like FF 31